# Print from enumerated list in python

Tags: python, list, numbered-list

I have imported a document. The items show up in a list. I have also taken input from a user, and it tells me where that input is in the list.

How would I print out that line of the list and the item above and below that line in the list? In my list I have `actor`, `name of movie`, `year`, and `role the actor played`. The middle line is the year so I have the user search for that and it should print out the title of movie and the role they played.

```
tom = open("TomHanks.txt", "r")
hanksYear = (input('What year would you like to see Tom Hanks movies?'))
hanksRead = tom.readlines()

with open("TomHanks.txt", "r") as f:
    hanksArray = f.read().splitlines()

for i in [i for i, x in enumerate(hanksArray) if x == hanksYear]:
    print(i)
```

The `print(i)` gives me the number in the list that year pops up. If it is there twice it gives me both spots that the year pops up. I would like to print that year then print the spot above and below that item in the list.

Comment: Do you need to open the file for reading twice?

Comment: Check what if `x == hanksYear` is doing. How does x look like in `for i, x in enumerate(hanksArray)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad since you need the majority of an algorithm in order to solve this. Each step of this is potentially a separate question and it's unclear what parts you do and don't understand.

Comment: print(hanksArray[i-1], hanksArray[i], hanksArray[i+1]) - is that what you want?

Comment: Sir you are amazing that is exactly what I wanted I cant believe it was that easy

Comment: @anti1869 Please post a proper answer so that the question can be closed. Comments are not meant for answers

Comment: @CrakC OK, just wasn't sure what author was intended to do

Comment: @JustinMitchell Please accept the solution that solved your problem so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing solution in answer separately for readability of others.

```
for i in [i for i, x in enumerate(hanksArray) if x == hanksYear]:
        print(hanksArray[i-1])
        print(hanksArray[i])
        print(hanksArray[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution for you will be

```
for i in [i for i, x in enumerate(hanksArray) if x == hanksYear]:
    print("\n".join(hanksArray[i-1:i+2]))
```

There are numerous other problems with your code anyway

Comment: I know there are some problems with my code thank you for my help, I am a first year in college just working through it I take all feedback given and try to use it in future.  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot cleaner.

```
for line,val in enumerate(hanksArray):
    if val == hanksYear:
        print(hanksArray[line-1])
        print(val)
        print(hanksArray[line+1])
```